# Migrating from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, one with 100,000 records of data and one with "not interested"

The table "businesses" has a "BusinessID | around 10 other info columns

the table "notinterested" has a "BusinessID" and a DateOfCall.

Currently i am filtering out the data by checking if, if exists in notinterested and the DateOfCall is less than 42 days then dont show it in the select. (code below).

```
SELECT * FROM businesses where PostCode like '" . $pcode . "%'
and BusinessType like '%$btype%'
and BusinessID NOT IN (SELECT BusinessID FROM telesales.notinterested WHERE NOW() BETWEEN DateOfCall and (DateOfCall + INTERVAL 42 DAY) ) 
and AppointmentDate is null
ORDER BY RAND() limit 100"
```

It was fine at first but now "notinterested" has around 30,000 records it is getting very sluggish especially with one letter postcodes.

I have added a new column to the bussinesses table called "notinterested" and i want to put a date in there instead.

What is the easyiest way to migrate the DateOfCall from the "notinterested" table into the new column in "Businesses"? Im a bit worried as its live data and dont have much time

Comment: use not exists vs not in. not in has to compare every record not exists can exit early once an single record is found.  Order by rand is also going to be slow as it has to generate a random value for each record and then limit to the first 100.  and and do you have to do like's with %% on both sides?  I would think BusinessType could be an equalitycheck vs a LIKE.  I can understand postcode with +5 or not... but business type... not so much

Comment: If you have no choice but to run a query on a live database, always back it up to a test database and test the query there first! If someone here makes even the slightest mistake and you blindly run it, the result can be devistating!

Comment: Thanks for the advice i didnt know that

Comment: Depending on how well(or rather "how little") MySQL's internal optimizer is helping you, reworking the `NOW() BETWEEN DateOfCall and (DateOfCall + INTERVAL 42 DAY)` condition to something like `DateOfCall BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 42 DAY AND NOW()` or perhaps even just `DateOfCall > NOW() - INTERVAL 42DAY` could help a lot (especially if `DateOfCall` is indexed). _`DateOfCall + INTERVAL 42 DAY` is likely making any index on the field unusable, as any function operation on a field does._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your original question, you can run this query to update the added date field.

```
UPDATE businesses
INNER JOIN
(SELECT BusinessID, MAX(DateOfCall) maxdateofcall FROM telesales.notinterested WHERE NOW() BETWEEN DateOfCall AND (DateOfCall + INTERVAL 42 DAY) GROUP BY BusinessID) recentnotinterested
    ON businesses.BusinessID = recentnotinterested.BusinessID
SET businesses.notinterested = recentnotinterested.maxdateofcall;
```

Comment: Hi rick thanks for the answer but it has only updated 1 row, any idea why?

Comment: Hi @AlexBanerjee, I forgot the GROUP BY statement. I've edited the answer. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Worked a treat, thank you. Still a little slow tho.

Edit: Didn't work a treat but its a little better.

```
SELECT * FROM businesses where PostCode like '" . $pcode . "%'
and BusinessType like '%$btype%'
and NOT EXISTS (SELECT b.BusinessID FROM businesses b
                left join telesales.notinterested ni on ni.BusinessID = b.BusinessID
                WHERE (ni.DateOfCall > NOW() + INTERVAL 42 DAY))
and AppointmentDate is null
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: Did you try the date handling suggestion on your original query? `NOT EXISTS` may not always be faster; since it required you to change it to a correlated subquery, the subquery must be executed for every row in the outer query; reverting back to the `NOT IN` version results in a costlier subquery, but one that is only run once for the entire outer query (since it will no longer be correlated).